# how can we merge two or more aws cloudformation templates

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, aws-serverless, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

Is there any way to include two or more AWS cloud formation templates into a final template like we do in serverless? I had a project which contains different yaml files for a group of resources. For each group i had a cloud formation template earlier which is a yaml file of serverless where i can include the file using ${file path/name}. If we cannot include like that is there any script such that it includes all the resources and outputs at one place in order.

Comment: This might be better suited for another SE site: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117646/where-can-i-ask-questions-on-cloud-computing

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this if you develop your own [macro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html) for that in CloudFormation. Otherwise you have to refactor your template to use [nested stacks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-nested-stacks.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try [Rain](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/rain). It's a development workflow tool for working with AWS CloudFormation. `rain merge` command can merge two or more CloudFormation templates.